# ABP SMTP Email Settings and test

Tags: email, smtp, abp

I am having issues with the SMTP email testing in ABP. It tells me it is sending the email okay, but it never gets received. Our SMTP server does not require any authentication so I have left those blank and it still doesn't work. I have also tried by telling it to use the default settings and this doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you use the ABP Mailkit ? You can check and investigate your configuration in this ABP email demo project -> https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/tree/master/EmailSendDemo